# Cannot find name 'classes'. TS2304? when trying to style with React + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styling, jss

I'm currently trying to add my own styles to my website and I've encountered this issue when I try to add a custom `className`.

> Cannot find name 'classes'. TS2304

Here is my code so far:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  aboutSection: {
    color:"red",
  }
});

class About extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='about-body'>
        <Grid container className ={classes.aboutSection} spacing={4} justify='center'>
          <Grid item sm={12}>
            <br></br>
            <h1>A Little More About Me!</h1>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            More about Me
          </Grid>
        </Grid>    
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default About;
```

Answer (score -1):

`classes` is a normal javascript variable, where do you expect it to come from? In the code given it does not appear to exist.

I think what you meant to do was use the `useStyles` hook in your component. Probably like this:

```js
const classes = useStyles();
```

The problem is, your component is a class, and hooks are not allowed in class components. You could convert it to a functional component, or use the [`withStyles` HOC](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api) for injecting styles.

Here is how it would look as a functional component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  aboutSection: {
    color:"red",
  }
});
const About = (props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className='about-body'>
      <Grid container className ={classes.aboutSection} spacing={4} justify='center'>
        <Grid item sm={12}>
          <br></br>
          <h1>A Little More About Me!</h1>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          More about Me
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

export default About;
```

Here is how it would look with the `withStyles` HOC:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = {
  aboutSection: {
    color:"red",
  }
};
class About extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = props;

    return (
      <div className='about-body'>
        <Grid container className ={classes.aboutSection} spacing={4} justify='center'>
          <Grid item sm={12}>
            <br></br>
            <h1>A Little More About Me!</h1>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            More about Me
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(About);
```

Comment: @positiveguy "snarky" seems pretty subjective. What i said is a fact. A lot of beginners get accustomed to things working almost magically and forget had underneath these fancy libraries it's just normal javascript and you have to use it as such.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing

```js
class About extends React.Component {
  const classes = useStyles();`
...
```

https://material-ui.com/styles/basics

Comment: Downvote because this answer is incorrect and will break. Hooks may not be used within class components. You can read about the rules of hooks [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)